# single caption under multiple figures using floatrow

Tags: floats, captions, floatrow

I am trying to place a single caption underneath four figures. I can place a caption underneath each figure, but that is not what I want.
I am using the floatrow package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption}

\def\mygraphcaption{Here are my graphs.}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{floatrow}[4]

\ffigbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,width=5.3cm,
  xmin=-2.8,xmax=2.8,ymin=-2.5,ymax=3.5,
  xlabel=$x$,   
  ylabel={$y$},
  xtick distance=1,
  ytick distance=1,
  xticklabel style={font=\tiny},
  yticklabel style={font=\tiny},
  title style={yshift=0ex,xshift=-15ex},
  x label style={yshift=-3ex,xshift=2ex,font=\tiny},
  y label style={yshift=2ex,xshift=-3ex,font=\tiny},]

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\ffigbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,width=5.3cm,
  xmin=-2.8,xmax=2.8,ymin=-2.5,ymax=3.5,
  xlabel=$x$,   
  ylabel={$y$},
  xtick distance=1,
  ytick distance=1,
  xticklabel style={font=\tiny},
  yticklabel style={font=\tiny},
  title style={yshift=0ex,xshift=-15ex},
  x label style={yshift=-3ex,xshift=2ex,font=\tiny},
  y label style={yshift=2ex,xshift=-3ex,font=\tiny},]



\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}


\ffigbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,width=5.3cm,
  xmin=-2.8,xmax=2.8,ymin=-2.5,ymax=3.5,
  xlabel=$x$,   
  ylabel={$y$},
  xtick distance=1,
  ytick distance=1,
  xticklabel style={font=\tiny},
  yticklabel style={font=\tiny},
  title style={yshift=0ex,xshift=-15ex},
  x label style={yshift=-3ex,xshift=2ex,font=\tiny},
  y label style={yshift=2ex,xshift=-3ex,font=\tiny},]



\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}


\ffigbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,width=5.3cm,
  xmin=-2.8,xmax=2.8,ymin=-2.5,ymax=3.5,
  xlabel=$x$,   
  ylabel={$y$},
  xtick distance=1,
  ytick distance=1,
  xticklabel style={font=\tiny},
  yticklabel style={font=\tiny},
  title style={yshift=0ex,xshift=-15ex},
  x label style={yshift=-3ex,xshift=2ex,font=\tiny},
  y label style={yshift=2ex,xshift=-3ex,font=\tiny},]

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{\mygraphcaption}
}

\end{floatrow}

\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `subfloatrow` environment as described in section '6.1 Managing of Float Parts With the subfloatrow Environment'  of the [`floatrow` manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) one can achieve the following result. Please be aware that the caption appears to be not horizontally centered as the 4 graphs are much wieder than the textwidth of the standard `article`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption}

\def\mygraphcaption{Here are my graphs.}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\ffigbox{
\begin{subfloatrow}[4]

%\ffigbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,width=5.3cm,
  xmin=-2.8,xmax=2.8,ymin=-2.5,ymax=3.5,
  xlabel=$x$,   
  ylabel={$y$},
  xtick distance=1,
  ytick distance=1,
  xticklabel style={font=\tiny},
  yticklabel style={font=\tiny},
  title style={yshift=0ex,xshift=-15ex},
  x label style={yshift=-3ex,xshift=2ex,font=\tiny},
  y label style={yshift=2ex,xshift=-3ex,font=\tiny},]

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%}

%\ffigbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,width=5.3cm,
  xmin=-2.8,xmax=2.8,ymin=-2.5,ymax=3.5,
  xlabel=$x$,   
  ylabel={$y$},
  xtick distance=1,
  ytick distance=1,
  xticklabel style={font=\tiny},
  yticklabel style={font=\tiny},
  title style={yshift=0ex,xshift=-15ex},
  x label style={yshift=-3ex,xshift=2ex,font=\tiny},
  y label style={yshift=2ex,xshift=-3ex,font=\tiny},]



\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%}


%\ffigbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,width=5.3cm,
  xmin=-2.8,xmax=2.8,ymin=-2.5,ymax=3.5,
  xlabel=$x$,   
  ylabel={$y$},
  xtick distance=1,
  ytick distance=1,
  xticklabel style={font=\tiny},
  yticklabel style={font=\tiny},
  title style={yshift=0ex,xshift=-15ex},
  x label style={yshift=-3ex,xshift=2ex,font=\tiny},
  y label style={yshift=2ex,xshift=-3ex,font=\tiny},]



\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%}


%\ffigbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,width=5.3cm,
  xmin=-2.8,xmax=2.8,ymin=-2.5,ymax=3.5,
  xlabel=$x$,   
  ylabel={$y$},
  xtick distance=1,
  ytick distance=1,
  xticklabel style={font=\tiny},
  yticklabel style={font=\tiny},
  title style={yshift=0ex,xshift=-15ex},
  x label style={yshift=-3ex,xshift=2ex,font=\tiny},
  y label style={yshift=2ex,xshift=-3ex,font=\tiny},]

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

%}

\end{subfloatrow}
}{\caption{\mygraphcaption}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```